# Do i have to add an auxiliary variable when adding a new equality constraint at a LP?

Tags: linear-programming, problem-solving, constraints, simplex-method

For example I have the following problem:
\begin{align}
&\textrm{min z}  = -2x_1 -x_2 +x_3 \\
&\textrm{s.t.} \\
& \qquad x_1 +2x_2 +x_3 \leq 8 \\
& \\
&\quad -x_1 +x_2 -2x_3 \leq 4 \\
& \\
&x_i \geq 0, i = 1,…,3
\end{align}

with the following optimal tableau:

```
-z  x1  x2  x3  s1  s2   RHS

-1  0   3   3   2   0    -16

 0  1   2   1   1   0      8

 0  0   3  -1   1   1     12
```

Let's say I want to add the following new constraint: $x_1 +x_2 = 3$.

Do I have to introduce an 'a' variable at my new tableau before I start doing E.R.O, to reoptimise the tableau?

Comment: I've made an edit. Please make a check if everything is fine an then give a reply.

Comment: @callculus42 aye all is good. Do you know the anser though?